# Dynamic loading ajax button click - how to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I make a loading button dynamic ?
this my code

```
var $this = $(this);
            $this.button('loading');
                setTimeout(function() {
                $this.button('reset');
            }, 2000);
```

when I click the button its loading for 2 second as define, while ajax is sending post request to the backend and its take a time depending what I send,

the question is. if ajax request have not done yet but the loading button have finish because it set manually for 2 but ajax take request for 5 second so how I make the loading button time become dynamic or finish until ajax request is done ?

Comment: Use the callback of the AJAX request to know when it's completed.

Comment: don't use an arbitrary timer. AJAX has an interface defined with callbacks you can execute when the request completes (or fails)

Comment: hi I thank u for answering myquestion.but can u prefer me a link so I can learn it or maybe u have a couple code to show me how ajax callback works ? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax see the `success`, `error` and `complete` callbacks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the `$this.button('loading');` before ajax script

Then, on `ajaxSuccess` or `ajaxComplete`, simply put the `$this.button('reset');` to reset the state of the button

Comment: this solved my problem thanks I put `$this.button('reset')` into ajax callbacks as they mention above

Answer (score 1):

Add `$this.button('loading');` before  ajax and `$this.button('reset');` after ajaxsucess return. Please check below ajax example will help you.

`$("#button").click(function(e) {`

```
e.preventDefault();

var $this = $(this);
        $this.button('loading');
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "",
  data: {
    },
  success: function(result) {
    $this.button('reset');
  },

});
```

});

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.